# Error ElasticApmAttacher (Elastic APM) on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, elastic-apm

I'm trying to use Elastic APM on IntelliJ on local environment but I have this error:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticApmConfig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: co/elastic/apm/attach/ElasticApmAttacher"
```

Nevertheless, the same project on Eclipse works.

I'm using this version in a springboot project with Java 11

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>co.elastic.apm</groupId>
    <artifactId>apm-agent-attach</artifactId>
    <version>1.39.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If it works in Eclipse, you have a problem with your build. Somehow the dependency jar isn't making it into the production environment.

Comment: Yes, the error is "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError co/elastic/apm/attach/ElasticApmAttacher" but I have the library correctly added and compiling

Comment: Do you run it using Maven goal?

Comment: No, I run it with IntelliJ